# google places API with ios maps

Tags: iphone, ios

I have just started looking into googles places API and in the documentations I have read this

**If your application displays Places API data on a map, that map must be provided by Google.**

And now that it seems as though apple is dropping google maps in replace for their own solution what dose that mean for people wanting to use this API on a map on an ios device?